# Find a cell value and fill other cells depending on the value of the cell

Tags: vba, excel

the setup:
I have one value x (which can be changed via a dropdown menu) in a cell in sheet A.
Check if the same value exists in sheet B and return the cell contents listed in the same column below until the first blank cell. Copy those cells to sheet A again.

For example:

Sheet 1, Column A contains a "Unit" header. Column B has a employees-header.
From that unit field I can choose via dropdown function a couple of Units (Sales, Marketing, programming, ...).

In sheet B you can find a set of mini tables.

There are the units listed per Building. Every of those 6 Buildings (1 Building per Column, A-F) has its own units listed in the same column. The units lists up some employees names and ends with a blank cell as separator for the next unit.

Sheet2:Column A

Building1 - Sales
Peter
Judy
Franz
Rico

Building1 - Marketing
Sandy
Aaron
Fred

Building1 - Programming
Sheldon
Lara

Sheet 2 Column B is the same like Building2 -Sales.....

Now in the dropdown in Sheet A, I select the value
"Building1 - Marketing"
Column B in Sheet A should now be filled with the Names of the employees in the Marketing Unit of Building1, that would be Sandy, Aaron and Fred.

That is an example though, but the ordering in the second sheet is like that...

I read about filldown, which I think is the wrong way. Also I could probably find x in sheet B, do a count on the values below until the blank comes, then use the value for selecting, copying and pasting the values.

How can this be done?

rgds

Comment: Please show us some code, then we can help you with any issues you encounter. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

Sheets("Feuil2").Select 'selects sheet 2

'finds what you chose in the dropdown list
Cells.Find(What:=Feuil1.MyDropDownList1.value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

'selects from the line below till the line before blank
Range(ActiveCell(2, 1), Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Address)).Select

Selection.Copy 
Sheets("Feuil1").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

---

I hope this will give you an idea.
You will have to make some modifications according to your sheet name and your dropdownlist name and so.

Good luck

Comment: Something like that is what my project now looks like. It works by now.
The work is not on this pc though and my Syntax may be wrong...
I'll try here:
dim cellfinder
set cellfinder = something the value of that specific cell
dim rngX
set rngX = worksheet("building1").Range("A:A").find(cellfinder)
set rngY = worksheet("building1").Range(rngX).End(xlDown)
Worksheets("Building1").Range("rngX, rngY").Copy _ 
    destination:=Worksheets("Employee").Range("B1")

Roughly. Something like that and this for each of the buildings. I've learnt alot more about vba in the past days than ever before :)